# Empty fields are not being updated in node edit forms

Tags: apache, drupal-7, content-type

I'm facing a weird problem in one of our Drupal site. The null/empty values for the fields ( like textfield/textarea) are not being submitted in any node edit forms.

Let's say I've a text-field called "*name*" and having '*Krishna*' as value in that field. If I emptied the field and submit the node, the previous value (Krishna) is being updated (In other words the I can't see any change after submission but getting  'node has been update' successful message).

If I give any other value rather than emptying the field, the node is being updated with the given one.

I've setup the entire site in my local and getting no issues like that. So I think the issue would be at server side.

Any inputs on this would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've dig the issue bit more. In drupal whenever we empty the field it actually deletes the record from the database field table. It's happening in local instance but not in remote server. So I double checked the db privileges and everything looks good. Not sure what could be the issue.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, 
I can think of two options on top of my head at the moment. 
1) Your browser caching or saving your form values. or 
2) Somewhere a in a module or elsewhere you have form_alter altering submit values. 

Check in your field settings that you have set your field as a required (*) field, that way empty forms cannot be submitted also check the default value of that field in its settings.

Comment: @SanjokGurung If that would be the case it should not work in my local instance too. (Since I've taken same files and db from the server).

Comment: Sounds like remote server issue, if possible reset all server caches, restart the server engine. Check for server error/access logs. Check watchdog. or else try injecting a form_alter() and start debugging  with var_dump(); on the server.